# How to remove all duplicates from a list?

Tags: list, delphi, unique, delphi-xe7, spring4d

Consider this test app:

```
function RemoveDuplicates(const Input: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>;
begin
  // How to implement this function?
end;

var
  Enumerable: IEnumerable<Integer>;
  UniqueEnumerable: IEnumerable<Integer>;
begin
  Enumerable := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]);
  UniqueEnumerable := RemoveDuplicates(Enumerable);
  UniqueEnumerable.ForEach(
    procedure(const I: Integer)
    begin
      WriteLn(I);
    end);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

How can I implement the `RemoveDuplicates` function (this is called `nub` in Haskell)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use what is already there:

```
uses
  Spring.Collections,
  Spring.collections.Extensions;

function RemoveDuplicates(const Input: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>;
begin
  Result := TDistinctIterator<Integer>.Create(Input, nil);
end;
```

This supports lazy evaluation (means that Input is not getting processed before the resulting enumerable is getting processed). It is using a hashset (currently implemented as Dictionary) internally to keep track of the already found items (this happens inside the enumerator).

Why is that important? Because any operation that does a complete enumeration might cause unwanted performance impact if `Input` involves other costly operations which may by far outweigh any benefits of other approaches of removing duplicates (like putting it into a list and sort that). Also an IEnumerable is not guaranteed to be finite.

If between calling this function and enumerating the result the `Input` was changed that change is affecting the outcome of your enumeration whereas it would not be the case if you are not supporting lazy evaluation. If you are enumerating multiple times the outcome might be different (i.e. up-to-date) each time.

Comment: So elegant and simple!

Answer (score 4):

Jens's solution will work, but it has a rather slow running time of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

A better alternative if you have a long list is to
- Sort the list
- Compare every item with its successor.

This has a running time of O(n log n) for the quicksort + O(n) for the search for a total running time of O(n log n).

See the following **pseudo** code (don't have access to Delphi now).

```
function RemoveDuplicates(const Input: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>;
var
  List: IList<Integer>;
  i: integer;
begin
  List := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>;
  List.Assign(Input); //Copy input list to output.
  List.Sort;
  for i:= List.Count-1 downto 1 do begin
    if List[i] = List[i-1] then List.delete(i); 
    //if Comparer<T>.Equals(List[i], List[i-1]) then ....
  end; {for i}
end;
```

**Problems**
The problem with this approach is that the output (might) have a different order from the input. This may or may not be a problem.

**Benefits (or why the dictionary sucks)**
If the sorting is a cheap operation this will be the fastest approach.
The use of a dictionary carries high constant cost for the hashing.
Even though the hashing operation is O(1), it can get very expensive for large keys, because the hash will always process the whole key, whereas sorting comparison will stop as soon a a difference is detected. 
Further note that hashing is a much more expensive operation than a simple comparision (about 30x to 100x slower)!

Only when the list is huge does the better asymptotic running time of the dictonary kick in.

Comment: What hash function are you using on an integer? Or, in other words, much of what you have written here is plain wrong in this setting. You may have a point where hashing is expensive, but that's not the case here. No matter how expensive it is, for decently large data, well before RAM is full, you can expect hashing to win.

Comment: @david I was rather assuming that integer is just used as an example here. If you use the default bobjenkins lookup3 hash it will be quite slow even for an integer.

Comment: There are certainly many commonly used types which can be hashed efficiently. So "why the dictionary sucks" is a rather over dramatic and perhaps mis-leading statement. In my view. And isn't the default hash for an integer the integer itself? Surely that is true. Hmm, no it is not true. I wonder why not.

Comment: No system.generics.defaults pushes everything though the bobjenkins' lookup3 hash. Hence my assertion about the slowness. Using lookup3 makes sense if you're only using part of the integer (e.g. 16 out of 32) much fewer collisions that way.

Comment: Even so, I bet that for even modestly sized data the log n soon overtakes the hash cost.

Comment: This is why I've put faster hashes in fastdefaults. Will do a test to see when the standard and optimized hash wins out over sorting+dedup.

Comment: FWIW I recently solved a dedup perf issue with hashed lookup. I'm not even sure I compared with sorting. The thing is, usually, when the data is small enough for sorting to be fast, you don't care about the perf. Everything happens instantly. The asymptotic behaviour is invariably matters because when the log n bites, it really hurts.

Answer (score 3):

For performance reasons I suggest to use a <strike>sorted list</strike> dictionary.

```
function RemoveDuplicates(const Input: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>;
var
  Dictionary: IDictionary<integer, integer>;
  Item: integer;
begin
  Dictionary := TCollections.CreateDictionary<integer,integer>;
  for Item in Input do
    Dictionary.AddOrSetValue(Item, 0);     

  Result := Dictionary.Keys;
end;
```

Comment: A dictionary is O(n). Your approach is O(n log n).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, I don't get the point. How can a dictionary lookup for duplicates with a complexity of O(n)?

Comment: Because dictionary lookup is `O(1)` and there are `n` items to process.

Comment: Note that the dictionary has a high constant in its O(1) lookup time, so it is not as performant as you might think!

Answer (score 0):

Using an intermediate list:

```
function RemoveDuplicates(const Input: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>;
var
  List: IList<Integer>;
begin
  List := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>;
  Input.ForEach(
    procedure(const I: Integer)
    begin
      if not List.Contains(I) then
        List.Add(I);
    end);
  Result := List;
end;
```

This is obviously not the best performing solution, see the other answers for better alternatives.

Comment: This is the slowest possible approach and will have a horrible running time even for small lists.

Comment: Sure, but it's also the most straight-forward way. I was mainly posting it as a reference basis.